# Calculating eigenvectors - degrees of freedom in the calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider finding the eigenvectors of this matrix

> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 5 \\
> -1 & -4
> \end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1, -3$

So the eigenvector for $\lambda = 1$ satisfies $$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 \\
-1 & -4
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 1\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$

The equation I get from comparing the top row is $2x + 5y = x$ or $x =-5y$ and the equation I get from the bottom row is $-x-4y = y$ or, again, $x=-5y$.

There is one degree of freedom. Firstly, where do these degrees of freedom come from and why do we have them? What is the significance of them?

Secondly, if we now consider a triangular matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1, 4$

And so the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ would satisfy

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 4
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 1\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$

However, this time, the top row gives $x=x$ and the bottom row gives us $x=-3y$. So they give different information. And I'm not sure why in this case, comparing both rows does not give us this same information.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is another eigenvector. Also, you would probably do better to move everything to one side and solve homogeneous systems of linear equations.

Comment: $x=x$ and $x=-3y$  conflict nothing

Comment: @janmarqz Textbooks have always told me that comparing the lower elements and the upper elements give the "same" equation. So I was a bit confused about why this triangular matrix doesn't give the "same" equation and if there was any reason why (even though the equations don't conflict).

Comment: it is at $(\lambda1\!\!1-A)v=\vec0$ which one gets two proportional equations since $\det(\lambda1\!\!1-A)=0$

Comment: In your last example, the bottom row tells you that $x = 3y$, not $x = -3y$. The first row $x=x$ gives you no information, so only the second row imposes any constraint. It tells you that any eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ is of the form $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}3y \\ y\end{pmatrix} = y\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, i.e. any nonzero scalar multiple of $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.